# Not able to submit form data with jquery tagsinput style field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I am trying to  use tags in my form data ui but am unable to receive them in my controller. Extracts from the code are as below:

scripts included:

```
  jquery 1.8
  jquery.tagsinput.js
```

css files:

```
jquery css
jquery.tagsinput.css
```

jsp file:

```
<form method ="post" id="saveFruitFormId" name="saveFruitForm">
<div>
<textarea name="mytags" id="myTagsId" ></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

javascript file:

```
    //tagsinput is the class present in the plugin tagsinput css file
    console.log("tags to be sent to controller",$('form#saveFruitFormId .tagsinput').text());

$.ajax({

    url:myurl,
    data:{
    sendTags:$('form#saveFruitFormId .tagsinput').text()
    },
    type:'post',
    datatype:'json',
    success:function(data){
    //some meaningful work
    }
    });
```

Ctrl files :

```
public void saveFruit(@RequestParam (required=false)String sendTags, ResourceResponse response) throws IOException,ParseException{
System.out.println("received tag param from form ="+sendTags);
}
```

In the js console, I can see the tags value from textarea is being correctly read but in the Ctrl the tags value are not received by @RequestParam.

I must be missing something here. Any help please?

Comment: Please learn to format your separate pieces of code separately :)

Answer (score 0):

There was a mismatch in the request parameter being sent from the jsp and received in the Ctrl. A silly mistake, I could have been more careful. :(